# NetSuite Saved Search - Cash Transactions excluding Line of Credit Sweep Deposits

Tags: sql, oracle, netsuite, saved-searches

My goal is to show the sum of cash debit transactions excluding line of credit deposits (i.e. sweep transactions from the line of credit). I can isolate cash transactions but have had difficulty excluding transactions that have a debit to the cash general ledger account and a credit to the line of credit general ledger account. Any help would be appreciated.

The deposits from the line of credit account are posted as an "Other Deposit" type, which translates to `{type} = 'deposit'; {version} = '2'`. However, NetSuite will not let me include `{version}` as a criteria filter or in the results.

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far, ie. show some code, that people here can give comments and corrections on

Answer (score 0):

I was able to generate a search that is permissible but not an exact answer to my original question.

The information below describes the Cash In version of the Search.  There are two searches that correspond to the answer.  A Cash In and a Cash Out search.  They show cash received or disbursed each week, but net out sweeps to and from the line of credit.  In fact, the searches show the debit and credit associated with the sweep transactions, which is not ideal.  So, in the details of the search results you will see a positive (debit) amount and the same negative (credit) amount, which when added together, net to zero. So the assumption is that all debits and credits to and from the line of credit equal one another.  It is not perfect, but it will work for now and at least clearly show the assumption made, to the end user of the searches.

The end goal was to use the searches as KPIs (i.e. a single total value on a NetSuite dashboard for cash received and then cash disbursed.

This is the NetSuite Saved Search Criteria and Results for the Cash In version:

***Criteria:***

Account is Cash, Short Term Liabilities

Posting is True

((Account is Cash AND Amount(Credit) is Empty) OR

(Account is Short Term Liabilities AND Amount(Debit) is Empty))

***Results:***

Date

Transaction Name

Name

Memo

Account

Formula(Numeric)

-Summary Type: Sum

-Formula: CASE WHEN {debitamount} >= '0'  THEN {debitamount} ELSE ({creditamount} * '-1') END